Remote keyboard with USB dongle under Linux: how to detect keyboard is ON?
So, problem is simple: I use a keyboard in an linux app (developed in Go) and am trying to figure which keyboards are connected, through Bluetooth or USB.
Using a combination of listing event files under /dev/input and using udevadm info and evtest on them (root suid), I could figure that perfectly fine. The main issue I still have is, when my remote keyboard (seen as USB, since it uses a USB dongle) is off, the keyboard (actually the dongle) is still visible and the corresponding event is there, but obviously I can't know if the keyboard is on or not.
Since I'd like to remind the user to switch their keyboard on, is there an easy way to communicate with the dongle and figure out the keyboard state? (non proprietary commands)

What are the name and the PCI ID of your keyboard/USB dongle? Maybe that info is useful to answer this question.

Actually the device is supposed to work with any keyboard and not a brand or model in particular. I was expecting a generic code or test.
